# Regex is too greedy. Cannot find a way to fix it

Tags: regex

Is there a way to fix the following regex? I have included an example in regex101. Basically it captures too much and a wrong part between `()[]` tags. It kind of does what it's supposed to but in turn I lose text and another tag.

https://regex101.com/r/OPRCuh/1

regex:

```
\[(.+?)\]\((https.+?)\)
```

sample text

```
_“[Developer Interview](/blog/tags/developer_interview.html)” is a new series here at Semaphore blog. We’ll interview developers from some of the companies using [text text text](https://textapp.com) to find out how they work and share their insights with you.
```

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.+?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` pattern matches any char other than a line break char. So, it can match `[`, `]`, `(` and `)`, too, until it finds a valid match. Since the regex parses the string from left to right, the regex engine finds the first `[` and then finds `]` after `Interview`, then finds `(` before `/blog` but gives it up since it is not followed with `https`, but still goes on to match chars until it finds `(https` and thus returns a valid match.

You may use

```
r'\[([^][]*)]\((https[^()]*)\)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UqZwpb/1)

The `[^][]*` pattern matches 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and `[^()]*` matches 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much!